# Hiding specific menu items

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, ms-project

I am trying to hide menu items where they contain the word 'Benefits HIDDEN' in a quick launch list. I have been trying to get a script to work, but no avail so far. Using F12 in Edge, the class I want to hide is as follows;

```
<span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span>
```

Which sites under this DIV

```
<div class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox" id="zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch">
```

I was trying this kind of approach;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch *:contains('Benefits HIDDEN')").hide ();
});
</script>
```

But no luck!

Answer (score 1):

zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch is ID not a class, use #
eg:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch *:contains('Benefits HIDDEN')").hide ();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. That hides the whole menu because it contains some entries with 'Benefits HIDDEN' What I need is to just hide the options that are 'Benefits HIDDEN' and not the whole menu

Comment: Does this help? This is one of a few I would to hide:

<li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/project detail pages/benefit02.aspx?projuid=5261df9a-ec73-ea11-b09e-00155d08a801&amp;ret=0"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span></span></a></li>

Comment: man this not hide whole menu... only menu items what contains "benefits HIDDEN"
https://jsfiddle.net/pLdbcsoh/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class/id of element you want to hide as the main part of jQuery selector.
If you want to hide the li tag, you can use(static is the class of the li tag):

```
$(".static:contains('Benefits HIDDEN')").hide();
```

[image]

Best regards,

Amos