# Hiding an li item with a div / class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide items (li?) in a quick launch menu, where it says 'Benefits HIDDEN', the HTML is;

```
<div class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox" id="zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch">
    <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static" id="zz14_RootAspMenu">
        <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/">
                <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
<span class="menu-item-text">Defra Benefits Dev</span></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="static">
                <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Information</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="static selected"><a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="javascript:PDPInfrastructure.NavigateWSSPage(0,true)"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Site</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following with no luck

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch *:contains('Benefits HIDDEN')").hide ();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Comment: Duplicate [Hiding specific menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60988795/hiding-specific-menu-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since lots of elements contain that text (not just the `span` elements it's in, but the `li` the `span` is in, its `ul`, etc., etc. — even the `#zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch` element itself), you have to be more specific with your selector.

Ideally, add a class or something to the innermost element you want to hide. But you can also do it structurally. For instance, if you want to hide the `li`s:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch li ul li.static:contains('Benefits HIDDEN')").hide ();
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch li ul li.static:contains('Benefits HIDDEN')").hide ();
});
```

```html
<div class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox" id="zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch">
    <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static" id="zz14_RootAspMenu">
        <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/">
                <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
<span class="menu-item-text">Defra Benefits Dev</span></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="static">
                <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Information</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="static selected"><a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="javascript:PDPInfrastructure.NavigateWSSPage(0,true)"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Site</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That says that you only want to hide elements containing that text *if* they are `li` elements with the `static` class inside a `ul` that's inside an `li` that's inside the #zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch` element.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.menu-item-text').each(function() {
  this.textContent.trim() === 'Benefits HIDDEN' && $(this).closest('li').hide();
});
```

```html
<div class="noindex ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox" id="zz13_idPDPQuickLaunch">
  <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static" id="zz14_RootAspMenu">
    <li class="static">
      <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/">
        <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
<span class="menu-item-text">Defra Benefits Dev</span></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="static">
        <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Information</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="static selected"><a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/sites/pwa/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Benefits HIDDEN</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="javascript:PDPInfrastructure.NavigateWSSPage(0,true)"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Site</span></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop every "li" item and check the text inside of it firstly. Try this:

```
$(function(){

            var menu_items = $("#zz14_RootAspMenu").find("li");
          menu_items.each(function(idx,el){
            var current_text = $(el).find('.menu-item-text').text();

            if(current_text == "Benefits HIDDEN"){
              $(this).hide();
            }
          })


        });
```